# Laravel Spatie Permission Multi Models to Permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, permissions, roles, laravel-permission

I know how to assign permissions to user.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use HasRoles;
}

$user->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
```

In this case, in model_has_permissions table will be inserted like this.

```
permission_id=> $permission_id
model_type=> "App\Models\User"
model_id=> $user_id
```

I have Team Model and I want to give permission to Team too.
This is what I did.

```
class Teamextends Authenticatable
{
   use HasRoles;
}

$team->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
```

I wanted this result,

```
permission_id=> $permission_id
model_type=> "App\Models\Team"
model_id=> $team_id
```

But it didn't work for me.
Anyone has experience such as above things?
Should I make another table for it?
like `team_has_permission`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution!

```
class Team extends Authenticatable
{
   use HasRoles;
   protected $guard_name = 'web';
}

$team->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
```

This worked well.
In db table, it saved like this.

```
permission_id=> $permission_id
model_type=> "App\Models\Team"
model_id=> $team_id
```

Really awesome!

Comment: this solution works for me, tried different things but this is the simplest solution we have for this issue, thanks bro.